# How to change the increment property dynamically in Bryntum scheduler

Tags: javascript, extjs, bryntum-scheduler

I'm trying to use bryntum scheduler.

Is there any way to change Increment property dynamically or make a zoom in/out for it?

Comment: Which property do you want to update? Are you trying to create your own ViewPreset?

Comment: Well, I have Preset with  the following headerConfig:
`
 middle: {
            unit: 'MINUTE',
            increment: 10,
            dateFormat: 'H:i'
        }
`
but sometime I need to increase/decrease "interval" value.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating additional presets for the configurations you need, then just call switchViewPreset to change between those.  More info here:

http://www.bryntum.com/docs/#!/api/Sch.preset.ViewPreset

and here:

http://www.bryntum.com/docs/#!/api/Sch.preset.Manager

For zooming, check this example out: http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/zooming/zooming.html